# IIS 8 default Page set up

Tags: asp.net, iis-8

I have create two virtual directory for same Physical directory and try to set different default page for both virtual directory on IIS8 but fail to set  for the same ,please help for the same.

Comment: Why you fail? What have you tried and what is the result of those attemps?

Comment: @ deusExCore I would like to explain you the exact issue .I created a virtual directory with name test with a path D:\Proj\myapp and default document as login.aspx , now when i create another virtual directory with name test2 with the SAME path D:\Proj\myapp but with different default document as la_login.aspx then the default document when i browse is chosen from the virtual directory which i created first....in IIS 5 and IIS 6 i am able to get the different default pages but on IIS 8 it is being redirected to the same default document